# Getting Last Modified by Name of xlsx file

Tags: python, metadata, xlsx

I have an excel file that gets modified by a group of people and we need to keep track of when the file was last modified and by whom

I was able to retrieve the file properties through .properties but trying to figure out how to isolate the lastModifiedby and insert its value in to a column

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('Rec1.xlsx')
wb.properties.lastModifiedBy
```

It gets me the information I need but I am stumped on how to create a new column "lastmodifiedby" with the information provided in properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#write-a-workbook

Perhaps something like this?

```
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.cell(column=1, row=1, value=wb.properties.lastModifiedBy)
wb.save(filename='Rec1.xlsx')
```

Answer (score -2):

is this what you are looking for??

```
Dim lastModifiedBy
lastModifiedBy = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Author")
```

Comment: This is VBA not Python